# How do I convert an element in List to String using Stream Java 8

Tags: java

I have only one element in `List<String>` and I want to convert that to a `String` using `Stream` in `Java 8`

I tried this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> lineList = Arrays.asList("This is a test line");
    String lineString;
    lineString = lineList.stream().map(element -> lineString);
}
```

Comment: in java 8 you can also do this: `String lineString = String.join("", lineList);`

Comment: I don't quite understand. If you have only one element, why are you using a stream? You can just map it and return it as well.

Comment: You don't need to use streams because your list only has one element, and you don't need to use .map() because your list element is already a string. What exactly is your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this :
public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<String> lineList = Arrays.asList("This is a test line");
            String lineString;
            lineString = lineList.stream().map(Object::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
            System.out.println(lineString);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you've asked, in an unsafe way mind you, and also you should pay heed to the comments you've received.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> lineList = Arrays.asList("This is a test line");
    String lineString;
    lineString = lineList.stream().findFirst().get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to get one transformed element from a list like this for example :

```
List<String> lineList = Arrays.asList("This is a test line");
String lineString = lineList.stream().reduce("", (res, s) -> res + s);
```

It will work if you have 1 or many elements in lineList array and you can set the transformation in the lambda expression.